# How to deal with MagickWand C api having different include paths depending on system

Tags: c, imagemagick, magickwand

What I mean by that is that in the include directive, on some systems the path is given by

```c
#include <MagickWand/MagickWand.h>
```

While on other systems it's

```c
#include <wand/MagickWand.h>
```

I'm not sure what the correct path in any system is and I cannot find any information online. The [magickwand api guide](https://imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php) uses `MagickWand/MagickWand.h`, but on the [examples](https://imagemagick.org/MagickWand/) `wand/MagickWand.h` is used.

As far as I can tell both are valid and it could be either one on each system.

I plan on sharing the code with the public and I'd like to avoid the user having to modify the source code to make it the way it works for their system so is there something I can do to include the correct one programmatically?